# Add different active class for the buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a two `button` elements. I want to add a different active classes for that buttons. I have a button which contains a text and the second button is a rounded button color. On the button that contains a text I want to add an active class which the style is underlined text. For example when I click the button with text 'All' it will add an active class 'filter__color-all--active' and when I click the button color without the text, the active class of button with text 'All' will be removed and the clicked button color without the text will have an active class 'filter__color--active'. How can I do that?

```
this._parentElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.btn__color');
  const clicked = e.target.closest('.btn__color');

  if (!clicked) return;

  for (const color of colors) {
    color.classList.remove('filter__color--active');
  }

  clicked.classList.add('filter__color--active');
});
```

**Buttons:**

```
<button class="btn__color transition duration-300" data-color="all">All</button>
<button class="btn__color h-4 w-4 rounded-full transition duration-300" style="background-color: ${color}" data-color="${color}"></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.filter__color--active {
  @apply ring-1 ring-gray-500 ring-offset-2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `.closest`. You can just use `const clicked = e.target;`.

And if you want to make sure that clicked was performed on `button` only and also it should have text "**All**" then you can use `innerText`. Update the `if` condition to `if (!clicked.classList.contains('btn__color')) return;`.

Added `console.log` so you can have better idea what value for target value. You could do the same so that you can easily trace the issue and fix it in less time. Once done you should remove those `console.log`.

```js
var d = document.getElementById('dv');
d.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.btn__color');
  const clicked = e.target;

  // just for testing added below logs so it could be helpful to anyone who refers the answer.
  console.log(e.target, e.currentTarget);

  // Verify if click is not performed on button then return
  if (!clicked.classList.contains('btn__color')) return;

  // remove active classes from buttons
  for (const color of colors) {
    color.classList.remove('filter__color--active', 'filter__color-all--active');
  }

  // add relavent class to element based on text
  if (clicked.innerText != 'All')
    clicked.classList.add('filter__color--active');
  else
    clicked.classList.add('filter__color-all--active');

});
```

```css
.filter__color--active {
  @apply ring-1 ring-gray-500 ring-offset-2;
}
```

```html
<div id='dv'>
  <button class="btn__color transition duration-300" data-color="all">All</button>
  <button class="btn__color h-4 w-4 rounded-full transition duration-300" style="background-color: ${color}" data-color="${color}"></button>
</div>
```

---

**FYI**

- [event.target](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_target.asp) : The target property gets the element on which the event originally occurred, opposed to the [currentTarget](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_currenttarget.asp) property, which always refers to the element whose event listener triggered the event.
- [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) : The `closest()` method traverses the Element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns `null`.
- [Element innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) : The `innerText` property sets or returns the text content of an element.

Comment: I did that but I only wanted to do is they have a different active class when clicked. On the button which has a text content of 'All', I want to add an active class which the style is underlined text.

Comment: Updated answer. Used `innerText` property of element and updated the `if` condition.

Comment: It seems that the button with 'All' text only added an active class? It should be different active class. For example when I click the button All it will add an active class 'filter__color-all--active' and when I click the button color without the text, the active class of button All will be removed and the clicked button color without the text will have an active class 'filter__color--active'.